# Почему не устанавливается роль для пользователя

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Хочу установить роль пользователю, сейчас у него стоит `TENANT`, хочу изменить на `LANDLORD`. У меня это не работает также с другими, где связано с ENUM значениями. Делаю запросы Post,Get,Delete - всё хорошо.

Делаю запрос через Postman, но ничего не меняется, хотя запрос туда проходит. По какой причине роль может не меняться? [FULL CODE](https://github.com/Blacit/HomeRent/tree/master/src/main/java/task/homerent) Если не пригодится, то удалю. Также пытался просто вывести `user.setRole();` - всё удавалось, он показывал текущую роль пользователя.

В `properties` поставил `update`, ранее был `validate`

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Вот метод:

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user:write')")
    public void TenantAdd(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
        user.setRole(Role.LANDLORD);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user:write')")
    public void TenantAdd(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
        user.setRole(Role.LANDLORD);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

Вам надо добавить сохранение юзера в репозиторий.

Почитайте про эту настройку - она управляет БД целиком, а не отдельными запросами
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Comment: Да, я вот думал, что мы устанавливаем (setRole) и сохранять не нужно. Спасибо, про update знаю. Не хватало этой строки `userRepository.save(user);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135114/how-does-spring-jpa-hibernate-ddl-auto-property-exactly-work-in-spring